# How do I treat string variables as actual code?

Tags: c++, string, function, metaprogramming

That probably wasn't very clear. Say I have a `char *a = "reg"`. Now, I want to write a function that, on reading the value of `a`, instantiates an object of a particular class and names it `reg`.

So for example, say I have a `class Register`, and a separate function `create(char *)`. I want something like this:

```
void create(char *s)  //s == "reg"
{
    //what goes here?
    Register reg;  // <- this should be the result
}
```

It should be reusable:

```
void create(char *s)  //s == "second"
{
    //what goes here?
    Register second;  // <- this should be the result
}
```

I hope I've made myself clear. Essentially, I want to treat the value in a variable as a separate variable name. Is this even possible in C/C++? If not, anything similar? My current solution is to hash the string, and the hash table would store the relevant Register object at that location, but I figured that was pretty unnecessary.

Thanks!

Comment: It'd be handy if you could use that string as a key to some kind of map. Don't you agree?

Comment: You can't do this in C++, since it doesn't support dynamism to the necessary extent. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why? Why would you let anything other than you, the programmer, determine what your variables are _Called_? You choose your var-names, but once the code is compiled, the names are gone (sort of)... I fail to see the point anyway, but to answer: a HashTable with a `hash`, `char *` and `Register` member sounds like the sensible thing to do...

Comment: JavaScript is the language for you, though I would caution you that this question sounds a lot like you're asking questions about how to use a screwdriver to cut a board in half when what you really need in the first place is a drill. **Describe the business problem you're trying to solve with this crazy technique**. There is probably a better solution than the one you have in mind.

Comment: @PeterM: I don't necessarily mean classes - it could be basic data types or structs as well.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: what I actually intend to do is have a few Register objects; say a, b, and c. Then, I parse 'assembly' directives the user enters and based on the operand, select a particular Register object.

Comment: @vinit_ivar If there are so few of them, just hard code it. `if (strcmp("a", s) == 0) a = create();` etc

Comment: @Boann, there's potentially around 40, I'm really trying to avoid hard-coding. I think I'll go with the hash-table approach; I'll store pointers to each Register.

Answer (score 4):

Variable names are compile-time artifacts. They don't exist at runtime. It doesn't make sense in C++ to create a dynamically-named variable. How would you refer to it?

Let's say you had this hypothetical `create` function, and wrote code like:

```
create("reg");
reg.value = 5;
```

This wouldn't compile, because the compiler doesn't know what `reg` refers to in the second line.

C++ doesn't have any way to *look up* variables at runtime, so *creating* them at runtime is a nonstarter. A hash table is the right solution for this. Store objects in the hash table and look them up by name.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. C++ does not offer any facilities to process code at runtime. Given the nature of a typical C++ implementation (which compiles to machine code ahead of time, losing all information about source code), this isn't even remotely feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comment:
What's the point? A variable name is something the compiler, but -most importantly- *you*, the programmer, should care about. Once the application is compiled, the variable name could be whatever... it could be mangled and senseless, it doesn't matter anymore.
You read/write code, including var-names. Once compiled, it's down to the hardware to deal with it.

## Neither C nor C++ have `eval` functions

Simply because: you only compile what you need, `eval` implies input later-on that may make no sense, or require other dependencies.
C/C++ are compiled ahead of time, eval implies evaluation at runtime. The C process would then imply: pre-process, compile and link the string, in such a way that it still is part of the current process...
Even if it were possible, `eval` is always said to be evil, that goes double for languages like the C family that are meant to run reliably, and are often used for time-critical operations. The right tool for the job and all that...

A HashTable with objects that have `hash`, `key`, `Register`, `collision` members is the sensible thing to do. It's not that much overhead anyway...

## Still feel like you need this?

Look into the vast number of *scripting* languages that are out there. Perl, Python... They're all better suited to do this type of stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you need some variable creation and lookup you can either:

- Use one of the scripting languages, as suggested by others
- Make the lookup explicitly, yourself. The simplest approach is by using a map, which would map a string to your register object. And then you can have:

> ```
> std::map<const char*, Register*> table;
>
> Register* create(const char* name) {
>     Register* r = new Register();
>     table[name] = r;
>     return r;
> }
>
> Register* lookup(const char* name) {
>     return table[name];
> }
>
> void destroy(const char* name) {
>     delete table[name];
>     table.erase(name);
> }
> ```

Obviously, each time you want to access a variable created this way, you have to go through the call to `lookup`.